# "Enlightened" badge has turned Portugese

Tags: bug, badges

So today I checked my stats on Stackoverflow, and noticed that I've been awarded a [esclarecido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esclarecido) badge.

Which seemed a bit odd.

A closer look at [the badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges), and it looks like the Enlightened badge has been translated into Portugese (including its description on the badges page). The rest of the badges are all still in English.

Comment: Are you *really* enlightened, though? Or are you just esclarecido?

Comment: It does not appear to have turned Portuguese for me. However, I'm turning Japanese, I think I'm turning Japanese, I really think so.

Comment: I'm curious.... Have you been to a foreign language SE site recently? I'm wondering if that could be a possible cause... If not... What an odd, random bug.

Comment: @Kendra I suspect it's regression or something related to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235277

Comment: @StevenV I suspect you're right. Good catch. :)

Comment: I'm not aware of having been on any non-English SE sites recently, but it's possible I guess. Kendra's link seems more likely. But yes, either way it is indeed an odd, random bug. And kinda entertaining. :-)